# Include board margin in PDF output

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I'm designing a flex PCB to place on the back of a human hand and I need to print it out once in a while to compare the shape. In the output job file I have included the PCB printouts under Documentation but I can't seem to find any layer corresponding to the board margin.

Comment: You create the outline yourself on a mechanical layer (one that does not result in copper or silk screen or solder mask or solder paste). You can pick a new one that isn't currently in use. When printing the PDF you include that layer if you want it to print.

Comment: @Spehro, current Altium versions store the "board outline" seperately, not on any "layer" (although of course you can still use a layer if you want to give your fab a gerber layer with the outline). There is a command something like "Create objects from board outline" and "Create board outline from objects" for copying the outline to/from normal layers. Unfortunately I'm not at my desk at the moment to check the exact name of the command.

Comment: @ThePhoton We're still using Summer 09 so maybe behind the times here, but the board house wants to see a gerber layer with the outline IME. I would **never** send design files to a board house.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you. That did the trick. The command was **Create Primitives from Board Shape** under Design->Board Shape. If you don't mind add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Spehro, if you switch to ODB++, I believe the board outline is treated specially, so no design layer is needed to give the outline to the fab. With gerbers, yes, I still copy the outline to a mechanical layer or keep-out layer and give it to the shop that way.

Comment: @chamod, Since you found the exact wording, feel free to answer your question for yourself. This is encouraged to help future readers with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, Altium doesn't use a layer for board shape which is defined separately. But it's possible to copy the board outline to a mechanical (or any) layer using the command **Create Primitives from Board Shape** under Design->Board Shape while in the 2D layout mode. This is useful when generating gerbers as well.